# Github Actions + Node JS + Azure Windows Web App + Web.Config gets overwritten

Tags: azure-web-app-service, github-actions

So, after much wrangling, I was able to get a one of my node js apps to deploy to azure web app via github actions.

The full code repo with the yaml configuration, is available here. https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/GitHubActionsNodeJS

Now, I find an odd problem. After each deployment, this specific line in the web.config, becomes like this.

```
   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
```

and, I have to manually go and do this.

```
   <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/index.js"/>
```

So, is there anything I can do to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Your YAML file is clearly the problem,

`zip release.zip ./* -r` packs up everything including your source code, but you should only pack up whatever in the `dist` folder.

You should use `cd dist && zip release.zip ./* -r` instead. Then you edit other parts of the YAML file to adapt to this change.

Comment: ah, I see. I am just a bare bones tutor trying to teach some essential continous deployment to my students. we simply don't have the time or the money to learn YAML to do this part you suggested, "edit other parts of the YAML file to adapt to this change." we just don't have the skill man. but, I will log this for future reference, when I can invest more time into YAML. Thanks. meanwhile, I will juts ask my students to edit the web.config manually, till someone else comes along and helps us out. thank you again.